# What are the -DPOSIX and -DXWINDOWS flags for in Makefiles?

Tags: linux, make, makefile, posix

I see -DPOSIX has something to do with POSIX compliancy...which I can kinda get my head around because my program uses a posix library (pthreads) but I can't dig up anything relevant on what -DXWINDOWS is for or why it's there.

Comment: Because you building an app that requires XWindows (headers, libraries ...)

Comment: That's what I figured it was for...but it's not.  It's command line only.  I just compiled without it and it worked fine.

Comment: What happens if you remove it and do a `make clean`?

Comment: it works perfectly, I'm guessing it was there for some other part of the code and possibly ignored when the CLI applications got built.

Comment: You have your answer then ;)